How to calculate cumulative counts for consecutive 0 or NaN values after a condition in pandas?
I need help creating a new column in my DataFrame that counts consecutive rows where approved_amount is either 0 or NaN. The conditions for this calculation are as follows:
Start counting only after the first occurrence of an approved_amount > 0 for each id. Some IDs initially have only NaN values, which should be ignored until the first positive approval occurs.
Reset the counter to NaN after the last approved_amount > 0. Some IDs stop making approvals and only log NaN afterward. In this case, I want the consecutive_zero_approved_amount to display NaN.



creation_timestamp
id
approved_amount
consecutive_zero_approved_amount




2019-04-05 08:55:32
1
NaN
NaN


2019-04-05 08:55:32
2
NaN
NaN


2019-05-08 10:48:10
1
100
0


2019-05-08 10:48:10
2
200
0


2019-05-25 19:15:53
1
0
1


2019-05-25 19:15:53
2
1000
0


2019-06-01 12:30:00
1
0
2


2019-06-01 12:30:00
2
NaN
NaN


2019-06-10 14:20:15
1
NaN
NaN


2019-06-10 14:20:15
2
NaN
NaN



EDIT: This code seems to work, but it's excruciatingly slow.
# Sort the DataFrame by id and creation_timestamp
df = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'creation_timestamp']).reset_index(drop=True)

# Define a function to calculate consecutive non-approved counts
def calculate_consecutive_non_approved(group):
    count = 0  # Initialize counter
    result = []  # To store results for this group
    started_counting = False  # Flag to indicate if we started counting

    for amt in group['approved_amount']:
        if amt > 0:
            if not started_counting:
                started_counting = True  # Start counting after first approved amount
            count = 0  # Reset counter on approved amount
        elif started_counting:
            count += 1  # Increment counter only if we have started counting
        result.append(count if started_counting else None)  # Append count or None if not started
    return result

# Apply the function to each id group
df['consecutive_non_approved_count'] = df.groupby('id').apply(
    lambda group: calculate_consecutive_non_approved(group)
).explode().astype(float).reset_index(drop=True)

# Drop rows after the last approved_amount > 0 for each ID
def drop_after_last_approved(group):
    last_approved_index = group[group['approved_amount'] > 0].index.max()
    return group.loc[:last_approved_index]

df = df.groupby('id').apply(drop_after_last_approved).reset_index(drop=True)


What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

I added one example of a code snippet. I've tried several different approaches. The problem is that all IDs are not active throughout the data, but the ID-specific rows are still logged for all timestamps.

The question is not clear, and your example looks ambiguous. Could you simplify the problem to a single 'id' with only relevant columns, if possible?

Maybe explaining the use case will help. This is data from a platform where you get offers from +20 entities (id). Sometimes, these entities are offline. The way to spot this is that offer requests are coming in, but the entity does not approve any amounts in a long time. Thus, I want to create an indicator that tracks the number of consecutive approved_amounts = 0. The problem is that the entities have started and ended on the platform at different times, making all the average statistics unreliable, so I don't know where to set the boundaries.

I would use two masks and Series.groupby.cumsum:
# only consider non-NA rows
m1 = df['approved_amount'].notna()
# identify null rows
m2 = df['approved_amount'].eq(0)

# among the non-NA rows
# increment the count on 0
df['consecutive_zero_approved_amount'] = m2[m1].groupby(df['id']).cumsum()

Output:
    creation_timestamp  id  approved_amount  consecutive_zero_approved_amount
0  2019-04-05 08:55:32   1              NaN                               NaN
1  2019-04-05 08:55:32   2              NaN                               NaN
2  2019-05-08 10:48:10   1            100.0                               0.0
3  2019-05-08 10:48:10   2            200.0                               0.0
4  2019-05-25 19:15:53   1              0.0                               1.0
5  2019-05-25 19:15:53   2           1000.0                               0.0
6  2019-06-01 12:30:00   1              0.0                               2.0
7  2019-06-01 12:30:00   2              NaN                               NaN
8  2019-06-10 14:20:15   1              NaN                               NaN
9  2019-06-10 14:20:15   2              NaN                               NaN

